# calling js files after adding a content

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, tinymce

I was wondering how to recall all the js files in the iframe head after adding content.

for eg - in tinyMCE after adding a table I want to load jquery mobile files in the iframe head (send a call) so the js files will be able to identify the attributes. such as data-role="page .

Comment: Code? Examples? Please elaborate

Answer (score 2):

There is a standard way of loading CSS into the document head. Checkout the [loadCSS](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.dom.DOMUtils.loadCSS) function provided by the Tinymce API:

```
// Loads a CSS file dynamically into the current document
tinymce.DOM.loadCSS('somepath/some.css');

// Loads a CSS file into the currently active editor instance
tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.loadCSS('somepath/some.css');

// Loads a CSS file into an editor instance by id
tinyMCE.get('someid').dom.loadCSS('somepath/some.css');

// Loads multiple CSS files into the current document
tinymce.DOM.loadCSS('somepath/some.css,somepath/someother.css');
```

To load js files into the head is possible. We use something like this

```
doc = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getDoc();

script = doc.createElement('script');
script.src = 'http://example.com/whatever_you_want.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';

head = doc.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
head.appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$.getScript`

this is the syntax

```
 $.getScript("ajax/test.js")
 .done(function(script, textStatus) {
    console.log( textStatus );
 })
 .fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {
    $( "div.log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxError handler." );
 });
```

and get script actually can ajax inside , can be said as shorthand for this

```
 $.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: "script",
  success: success
});
```